# Eclipse not Detecting Attempt to Upgrade from Luna to Mars

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to upgrade my installation of Eclipse from Luna to Mars, but I am having an issue with Eclipse not finding any updates even though I have added the Eclipse Mars repository to the list of available software sites. Whenever I run the update check, all I get is a message saying "No updates found." How can I get the upgrade to work?

[image: Available Software Sites]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did resolve this issue, so I downloaded the new version of Eclipse and reinstalled everything. Since doing so, other issues that I have had with Eclipse in the past that I previously ignored seem to have been resolved.

Comment: I see your point. How do you recommend migrating plugins and projects, respectively?

Comment: @fheub As far as migrating plugins are concerned, I just copied the URLs for the different update repositories for all my plugins and added them back to the list of repositories to check for updates from in the new version of Eclipse. As far as migrating projects is concerned, just reopen the projects that you want to work on. You'll have to redefine your default workspace on the first run.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds feasible. (EDIT: removed my reference to Eclipse Optimizer (zeroturnaround plugin) upgrade which is just a link to the eclipse wiki)

Answer (score 7):

1. Add the following sources to your available software list (`Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites > Add`):

   - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/
   - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5
2. Remove the old sources (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/ and http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4).
3. Go to `Help > Install New Software` and select http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5 from the `Work with:` dropdown. It should be called `The Eclipse Project Updates`.
4. Tick `Eclipse Java Development Tools > Eclipse Java Development Tools` and `Eclipse Platform > Eclipse Platform` and then click `Next`. See the following image (yours won't be greyed out - I've already upgraded).

[image: Eclipse Upgrade]

5. On the next screen, you may be asked to remove out of date plugins (due to broken / missing dependencies).
6. Your will be prompted to restart Eclipse. When it restarts, you will be greeted with an Eclipse Mars splash screen.

Comment: I was having the same problem as the OP and this is the only solution that worked given my needs. Having many projects requiring many different plugins for work, and with highly restrictive security policies, a clean install isn't an option for me. Thank you so much for this clear and effective solution.

Comment: I know this is old, and I have posted a response detailing what I actually did to fix the problem, but I will respond anyway. In the past, this method had always worked for me to upgrade, but in this case, it did not. I never figured out why.